# does stateful map operation of ordered stream process elements in deterministic way?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading about java streams API and I encountered the following [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html):

> The operation `forEachOrdered` processes elements in the order specified by the stream, regardless of whether the stream is executed in serial or parallel. However, when a stream is executed in parallel, the map operation processes elements of the stream specified by the Java runtime and compiler. Consequently, the order in which the lambda expression `e -> { parallelStorage.add(e); return e; }` adds elements to the `List` `parallelStorage` can vary every time the code is run. For deterministic and predictable results, ensure that lambda expression parameters in stream operations are not stateful.

I tested the following code and in fact, it works as mentioned:

```java
public class MapOrdering {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List < String > serialStorage = new ArrayList < > ();

    System.out.println("Serial stream:");
    int j = 0;
    List < String > listOfIntegers = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) listOfIntegers.add(String.valueOf(i));

    listOfIntegers.stream().parallel().map(e - > {
      serialStorage.add(e.concat(String.valueOf(j)));
      return e;
    }).forEachOrdered(k - > System.out.println(k));;
    /* 
    // Don't do this! It uses a stateful lambda expression.
    .map(e -> { serialStorage.add(e); return e; })*/

    for (String s: serialStorage) System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

**output**

> Serial stream:
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   null
>   null
>   80
>   90
>   50
>   40
>   30
>   00

questions:

1. The output changes every time I run this. How do I make sure that the stateful map operation is executed in order.
2. map is an intermediate operation and it only starts processing elements
   until terminal operation commences. Since a terminal operation is
   ordered, why is a map operation *unordered*, and tends to change results
   every time when working with stateful operation?

Comment: so `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` is the printout of `forEachOrdered(k->System.out.println(k))` and `null null 80 90 50 40 30 00` comes from the loop `for(String s:serialStorage)System.out.println(s)`? Sidenote: since you don't actually `map`, you could use `peek` in that place. And to do it really right you should use `.map(e -> e.concat(String.valueOf(j))).collect(Collectors.toList())` and safe the result as `serialStorage` That way you don't get `null`s and actually all 10 result values, not some random result because of concurrently adding to an unsafe collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got *lucky* to see that `serialStorage` has all the elements that you think it will, after all you are adding from multiple threads multiple elements to a *non-thread-safe* collection `ArrayList`. You could have easily seen `null`s or a `List` that does not have all the elements. But even when you add a `List` that is thread-safe - there is absolutely no order that you can rely on in that List.

This is explicitly mentioned in the documentation under *side-effects*, and intermediate operations should be side effect-free.

Basically there are two orderings: *processing order* (intermediate operations) and *encounter order*.  The last one is preserved (if it is has one to begin with and stream intermediate operations don't break it - for example `unordered`, `sorted`).

Processing order is not specified, meaning all intermediate operations will process elements in whatever order they feel like. Encounter order (the one you see from a terminal operation) will preserver the initial order.

But even terminal operations don't have to preserve the initial order, for example `forEach` vs `forEachOrdered` or when you collect to a `Set`; of course read the documentation, it usually states clearly this aspect.

Comment: so there is no way to specify processing order ?

Comment: @amarnathharish no, but since intermediate operations are supposed to be side effect free, you should not care about this. And if you do, than streams are probably not the right tool

Comment: It should be emphasized that the processing of the terminal operation still doesn’t have to be in a defined order (which the exception of `forEachOrdered `), e.g. when you do `collect(mapping(functionWithSideEffect, toList()))`, it still is non-deterministic. Only the final result, i.e. the returned `List`, will be consistent with the encounter order.

Comment: so basically `sideeffects` shouldn't be a problem when you are working with serial stream as `foreach` method works in deterministic(*even when the stream is unordered*) way in serial stream with consistent result  : and `interference` shouldn't be a problem in serial stream as a single thread is going to change the state of source no need to work with conurrent data sourceand result will be consistent : and **stateful intermediate operations** also doesn't matter when you are working with serial stream since result will be  consistent. does my assumptions hold true ?

Comment: @amarnathharish no. first of all adding `unordered` intermediate operation to a stream pipeline does not shuffle the source elements inside the stream on purpose. All it does it sets a flag, *at the moment, in the current implementation*; but things could change. So adding `unordered` is just a flag inside the stream that could be leveraged or not, in case of sequential streams it is not. And that is ok, since you said, that you don't care about order, always returning *the same* result is fine, since, well, you explicitly said you don't care about that order.

Comment: @amarnathharish even in the single threaded scenario you could in let's say java-15 be in trouble when things could somehow change and those intermediate operations could be run in some undefined order; and the documentation explicitly says that this is bad to do (read `prohibited`). There is one more aspect here: `Stream.of(1,2,3).map(x -> {Syso("mapping");  return x + 1;}).count()`, run this in java-8 and java-9...

Comment: i did its producing consistent result, im not going to incorporate state and interference in my code im just trying to unerstand `int inkl=(int) Stream.of(1,2,3).map(x -> {System.out.println(("mapping")); return x + 1;}).count();
  System.out.println(inkl);`

Comment: @amarnathharish that is not the point... in java-9 `map` will *not* be executed, at all.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to answer your 2 questions, while adding to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51987180/1876620)...

> 1. output changes everytime i run this. how to write code to process statefull map operation in an ordered way?

[Stateful map operations are discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) and you shouldn't use them, even for sequential streams. If you want that behaviour, you'd better use an imperative approach.

> 2. map is intermediate operation and it only starts processing elements until terminal operation commences.since terminal operation is ordered ,why map operation is unordered and tend to change results every time when working with statefull operation?

Only `forEachOrdered` respects *encounter order* of elements; intermediate operations (such as `map`) are not compelled to do so. For a parallel stream, this means that intermediate operations are allowed to be executed in any order by the pipeline, thus taking advantage of parallelism.

However, bear in mind that providing a stateful argument to an intermediate operation, (i.e. a stateful `mapper` function to the `map` operation) when the stream is parallel, would require you to manually synchronize the state kept by the stateful argument (i.e. you would need to use a synchronized view of the list, or implement some locking mechanism, etc), but this would in turn affect performance negatively, since (as stated in the docs) you'd risk having contention undermine the parallelism you are seeking to benefit from.

**Edit**: for a terminal operation like `forEachOrdered`, parallelism would usually bring little benefit, since many times it needs to do some internal processing to comply with the requirement of respecting encounter order, i.e. buffer the elements.